# What would be a good approach of storing inexact/imprecise dates?

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime, database-design

In the application I'm working on, I need to store some metadata which includes dates that can be inexact. As an example, let's say that I want to store the release date of a product. Some examples of possible dates that could be in my data set:

- 2023-01-10 12:00:00 - we know exactly when it was released (including time), e.g. they had a release event at this time
- 2010-01-10 - don't know the time, but that was the exact date
- 2000-01 - no exact date, but we know it was in January
- 2000-Q1 - no exact date, but we know it was in the first quarter
- 1995 - no exact date, we only know the year
- 1990s - we don't know even the year, just that it was some time in the 90s

My goal is being able to provide a search filter that can handle all these different and inexact times. For context, I'm working in C#/.NET with PostgreSQL.

I'm thinking of storing the inexact date as a DateTime range (having a "Begin" and an "End"). Parsing basically means detecting the format (which can be done with a bit of Regex), and then generating the range based on that. Searching is a bit of a challenge, we basically need to calculate the intersection between this range and the queried range; I'm not sure if it can be done in SQL, but it can be done. One problem with this approach is converting this structure back to a string; I'm thinking of just storing the original string that I originally parsed.

Do you think this is a good approach? Do you have a better idea?

Comment: Add a postgresql tag to your question, to get accurate attention and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rahatur's answer is a good one, just lacking in implementation details.

To store an approximate date you'll need two pieces of information:

- The approximation itself, as a `DATE`.
- How precise that approximation is.

In your question you mention a variety of options. Let's stuff them in an enumeration for documentation purposes (and use from your C# code) and add a couple more resolution options:

```
enum EDatePrecision
{
    Century = 1,
    Decade = 2,
    Year = 3,
    Quarter = 4,
    Month = 5,
    Week = 6,
    Day = 7
}
```

We'll store the precision as a `TINYINT` in the database.

Next we need a way to determine the range of valid values covered by an approximation. This isn't too hard in SQL, so we'll define a couple of UDFs to do the work. In MSSQL that could be something like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ApproxDateLowerBound(@when DATE, @prec TINYINT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @prec
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEFROMPARTS((YEAR(@when) / 100) * 100, 1, 1)
        WHEN 2 THEN DATEFROMPARTS((YEAR(@when) / 10) * 10, 1, 1)
        WHEN 3 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), 1, 1)
        WHEN 4 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), CASE DATEPART(quarter, @when) WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 4 WHEN 3 THEN 7 ELSE 10 END, 1)
        WHEN 5 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), MONTH(@when), 1)
        WHEN 6 THEN DATEADD(d, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @when), @when)
        ELSE @when
    END;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION FUNCTION dbo.ApproxDateUpperBound(@when DATE, @prec TINYINT)
RETURNS DATE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE @prec 
        WHEN 1 THEN DATEFROMPARTS((YEAR(@when) / 100) * 100 + 99, 12, 31)
        WHEN 2 THEN DATEFROMPARTS((YEAR(@when) / 10 ) * 10 + 9, 12, 31)
        WHEN 3 THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), 12, 31)
        WHEN 4 THEN DATEADD(d, -1 , DATEADD(m, 3, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), CASE DATEPART(quarter, @when) WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 4 WHEN 3 THEN 7 ELSE 10 END, 1)))
        WHEN 5 THEN DATEADD(d, -1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@when), MONTH(@when) + 1, 1))
        WHEN 6 THEN DATEADD(d, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @when), @when)
        ELSE @when
    END;
END;
```

Now you can get some defined boundaries for your approximations and use `BETWEEN` for comparison.

---

A few notes...

#### `DATETIME` Values

Obviously the solution above is for dates only (notice all those places I used `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`). It can be extended to cover additional precision steps for hours, quarter hours, minutes, seconds... whatever you like. The logic should be fairly clear.

#### Other Approximations

The above works reasonably well for approximations like "some time in the 2020s" or "in the 21st century", but sometimes you mean "a month either side of" or "a few days around" instead. Just add these as additional options in the generating UDFs and all will be well. Widen the precision field size if you need to.

#### Performance

Computing the range every time is not necessarily ideal, performance-wise. You'd be better off storing that range somewhere, either in the table as extra fields or in a separate cache table keyed on the date and precision, then join that during your query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ApproximateDateRanges 
(
    [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Precision] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    RangeStart DATE NOT NULL,
    RangeEnd DATE NOT NULL
    
    PRIMARY KEY (Date, Precision)
);

CREATE TABLE Sample
(
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    ApproxDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ApproxPrec TINYINT NOT NULL
);

-- Some sample data

INSERT INTO Sample(ApproxDate, ApproxPrec)
VALUES
    ('2023-10-25', 4),
    ('2023-10-25', 5)

-- Update ApproximateDateRanges after modifying rows in `Sample`
MERGE INTO ApproximateDateRanges t
USING (SELECT DISTINCT ApproxDate [Date], ApproxPrec [Precision] FROM Sample) s
ON t.[Date] = s.[Date] AND t.[Precision] = s.[Precision]

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT([Date], [Precision], RangeStart, RangeEnd)
    VALUES(s.[Date], s.[Precision], dbo.ApproxDateLowerBound(s.[Date], s.[Precision]), dbo.ApproxDateUpperBound(s.[Date], s.[Precision]))

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    DELETE;

-- Query

DECLARE @targetDate DATE = '2023-12-01';

SELECT s.*
FROM Sample s
JOIN ApproximateDateRanges r ON s.ApproxDate = r.[Date] AND s.ApproxPrec = r.[Precision]
WHERE @targetDate BETWEEN r.RangeStart AND r.RangeEnd;
```

This gives a nice balance between query speed (faster than calling the UDFs in the query) and storage (smaller than storing the ranges in-record, especially when there are a lot of collisions). It is however more sensitive to missed updates of the `ApproximateDateRanges` table.

#### Pre-Calculated Ranges

In some cases where the full range of valid dates is restricted - say to the dates in the first half of this century or the last 70 years or something - then you can pre-calculate all of the date ranges and add them to a table. This way you don't have to worry about updating the `ApproximateDateRanges` table after every edit to the data in other tables... but you do have to fill in about 2.6K records for each valid year you want to cover.

Might not be for you. Not everyone wants to store a table with 0.25 million records that will mostly go unused. It's pretty fast though. (Check out how and why date dimensions are used in Data Warehouses.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keep the data as `DateTime` type. Then in another column store what type of date that is. For example if you store `2023-01-01 12:00:00` that could be 'no exact date, but we know it was in January' or you know the exact Date and Time.

While displaying use the second column to format the DateTime. For example

```
DateTime              | DateType
2023-01-01 12:00:00     DateOnly -> Ignore the time part
2023-01-01 12:00:00     DateTime -> You exactly know the Date and the Time
2023-03-30 11:59:59     Q1 -> Ignore the time part
2023-03-30 11:59:59     Q1 -> You exactly know the Date and the Time
```

Doing above will reduce the data Insert/Update/Delete oparations and data search will be lot easier. You only have to deal with the data filter and render logics. Which will be simpler.

Comment: I suggest storing two DateTime values to handle date ranges.  For exact dates, store the same date in both DateTime values.  The SQL WHERE clause would be NOT LESS THAN StartDateTime AND NOT GREATER THAN EndDateTime.

Comment: Wont that become a query performance issue? Like you have to compare the Time part of two dates and then decide if Time is relevant or not?

Comment: If you have `2023-03-30 11:59:59` in both start and end date then will you interpret it as Q1 release date or March release date as per the questioners requirement?

Comment: If the time is not relevant, the start time would be 00:00:00 and the end time would be 23:59:59.  I doubt anyone would search for an exact time.  The string version of an exact time would be for displaying that row.

Comment: That means you have to manipulate Time part while inserting right? Because user will not input Time part in most cases.

Comment: Yes, you have to create proper start and end date/time values.  You do the work when inserting to make the querying much easier.

Comment: This si the best solution from multiple angles. Uses native datatypes without modification - very simple. Simple to design queries, if necessary simple to create index on each or compound index. Lastly, easy to match data with application logic. Yes one must take the intial input and convert, but that is negligible to all the other processes which will consume the data over its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNIX timestamps.

Create two additional columns:

- `mid`

  - The midpoint of the timespan

    - Day of `2023-01-10` -> `2023-01-10 12:00:00`
    - Month `2000-01`  -> `2000-01-15:xx`
      -Calculated by appending the min and max values to the missing parts then add the values and divide by 2.
- `precision`

  - `mid` - min of the start above. + a small amount (or 2) of leeway

The start time is just the string "0000-01-01 00:00" string overwritten with the numeric data, and a similar replacement via lookup for the quarters.

The end time is the string "9999-12-31 12:59" overwritten with the numeric data, The final 0 on the decade must be removed in the s case. The Q replaced via lookup table. One last correction is in the number of days in a month.

ABS Subtract the UNIX timestamps and compare the value for the desired precision.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding storing the original string value alongside the converted value is a good idea, as it will be possible to analyze the effectiveness throughout use.

Regarding .Net with postgresql, I recommend using the DateTimeOffset type, it will finish the time until the time zone.

Regarding the value conversion, I leave the following idea.

1. Create an enum to classify the supported conversion types.
2. a method for sorting which enum sorts on.
3. a dictionary that has the enum as its key as its value, a function that receives a string and returns DateTimeOffset.
4. store the data with the time zone

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use three columns, the first two being Start and End - which define a 'range' - and the third column which simply stores the original data for any debugging purposes. Your application should calculate the datediff and come to a meaningful conclusion about the event era.

```
DateTimeStart           | DateTimeEnd          | OriginalString     (Meaning)
2023-01-01 12:00:00     | 2023-01-01 12:00:00  | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 (Exact time known)
2010-01-10 00:00:00     | 2010-01-10 23:59:59  | 2010-01-10 (the timespan is for one day, which means that we know the date, but not the exact time)
2000-01-01 00:00:00     | 2023-01-31 23:59:59  | 2000-01 (time span is one month, so somewhere in January 2010)
2000-01-01 00:00:00     | 2000-03-31 23:59:59  | 2000-Q1 (time span is three months, so a quarter)
1995-01-01 00:00:00     | 1995-12-31 23:59:59  | 1995  (time span is a year, so event happened in that year)
1990-01-01 00:00:00     | 1999-12-31 23:59:59  | 1990s (time span is a decade, so event happened in that decade)
```

Comment: this is similar to what I posted 4 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

A *n* columns date compound such as :
If precision of timing is the day :
YEAR NOT NULL, MONTH NULL, DAY NULL with a final column DURATION (default 1) and constraints as :
CHECK (MONTH IS NOT NULL AND DAY IS NULL OR MONTH IS NOT NULL AND DAY IS NOT NULL)

We do not want a DAY not NULL without a MONTH !

Exemples :

```
2010 1 10 + DURATION 1
2000 1 NULL + DURATION 31
2000 1 NULL+ DURATION 91
1995 NULL NULL + DURATION 365
1990 NULL NULL + DURATION 3653
```

This i what I use for History facts from middle age to actual dates

Of course you cans extend the principle to H M S

To rebuild the complete period just use :

```
BETWEEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR, COALESECE(MONTH, 1), COALESCE(DAY, 1)) AND
        DATEAD(DAY, DURATION, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR, COALESECE(MONTH, 1) COALESCE(DAY, 1))
```